# avr-gcc destructive optimizations

Tags: c, compiler-optimization, avr-gcc

I'm programming an Atmel ATtiny13a microcontroller using avr-gcc 4.8.2.

This is my c code:

```
#include <avr/io.h> 
#include <util/delay.h> 

int main(void) {
    DDRB = 1; // PB0 is output
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        PORTB = 1;
        _delay_ms(500);
        PORTB = 0;
        _delay_ms(500);
    }
    while(1);
}

void test(void) {
    DDRB = 1; // PB0 is output
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        PORTB = 1;
        _delay_ms(100);
        PORTB = 0;
        _delay_ms(100);
    }
}
```

The test function (fast blinking of an LED) is never called from the main function, so the controller should only enter the main function (slow blinking).

When I compile the code with `-O1`, everything works fine:

```
avr-gcc -std=gnu99 -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums -mmcu=attiny13 -DF_CPU=1200000   -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Os -c test.c -o test.o
avr-gcc  test.o -o test.elf
avr-objcopy -O ihex -R .eeprom -R .fuse -R .lock -R .signature test.elf test.hex
```

But if I use `-Os` (optimization for size) or `-O2`, the microcontroller runs the `test` function instead of the `main` function: The LED blinks quickly and never stops.

Is the `-Os` flag simply too dangerous to use, should it be avoided? Or is there something I can change in my code to avoid this kind of bug? The ATtiny13a only has 1K of flash, so size reduction is something important.

---

*Edit:* As suggested in the comments, here's the assembler diff with `-O1` and `-O2`: http://www.diffchecker.com/3l9cdln6

In there you can see that `-O2` changes the first section from `.text` to `.text.startup`.

```
--- test.o1.txt 2013-12-03 19:10:43.874598682 +0100
+++ test.o2.txt 2013-12-03 19:10:50.574674155 +0100
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@
 __SREG__ = 0x3f
 __tmp_reg__ = 0
 __zero_reg__ = 1
-       .text
+       .section        .text.startup,"ax",@progbits
 .global        main
        .type   main, @function
 main:
```

That's probably the main issue here. After some further testing I found that the culprit is the `-freorder-functions` optimization. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Perhaps consider compiling with the `-S` option, to compile to assembly only. You could look at or post the assembly for `-Os` and `-O2`, maybe there would be something obvious.

Comment: @Macattack: Thanks, you probaby pointed me to the right direction. See edit in original post for diff.

Comment: Here are some (nongnu docs)[http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/mem_sections.html] mentioning `.text` but information is sparse at best. Any idea what goes on in the steps after compilation? I know zero about those build steps.

Comment: @DaniloBargen the code you show in the diff is the same between `-O1` and `-O2` (only label name change). How can you have different behavior with the same code?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I did some further debugging, and found that the "culprit" was the `-freorder-functions` optimization. It is documented in the manpage as follows:

```
-freorder-functions
    Reorder functions in the object file in order to improve code locality.
    This is implemented by using special subsections ".text.hot" for most
    frequently executed functions and ".text.unlikely" for unlikely executed
    functions. Reordering is done by the linker so object file format must
    support named sections and linker must place them in a reasonable way.
```

The last line in the documentation explains the problem I was having/causing. If we look at the compile commands from the original question again:

```
$ avr-gcc -std=gnu99 -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct \
   -fshort-enums -mmcu=attiny13 -DF_CPU=1200000   -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes \
   -Os -c test.c -o test.o
$ avr-gcc  test.o -o test.elf
```

...we see that I was passing the optimization flags to the compiler, but not to the linker. I assumed that the `CFLAGS` only affect compilation and not linking, so I did not pass them to the linker, but in that case I was wrong.

The result: The assembly code was reordered by the compiler (including appropriate labels), but the linker did not consider these labels. And because the `test` function was placed before the `main` function by the compiler and not re-arranged by the linker, that was the code that was actually executed on the microcontroller.

So the solution turned out to be: **Compiler flags should also be passed to the linker!**

Comment: you just saved me hard times finding the bug. Kudos for that.

Answer (score 4):

I am aware that my response comes after ~2 years since this question has been asked, but I belive that there's still no correct, in-depth answer.

---

Let us begin with a little bit of theory:

> When you invoke GCC, it normally does preprocessing, compilation, assembly and linking. The “overall options” allow you to stop this process at an intermediate stage. For example, the -c option says not to run the linker. Then the output consists of object files output by the assembler.
>
> Other options are passed on to one stage of processing. Some options control the preprocessor and others the compiler itself. Yet other options control the assembler and linker; most of these are not documented here, since you rarely need to use any of them.

source: [GCC Online Docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC)

> LDFLAGS
>
> Extra flags to give to compilers when they are supposed to invoke the linker, ‘ld’, such as -L. Libraries (-lfoo) should be added to the LDLIBS variable instead.

source: [GNU make Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Variables)

As you can see, it is up to GCC (I will call it this way to distinguish from actual compiler; you can find it beeing called *C compiler frontend* or simply *compiler* though) which options will be passed to which tools and it appears that `-On` option isn't passed to the linker (you can check it by giving `-v` option to GCC). So invoking GCC without this option when it is supposed to do only the linking is OK.

The real problem is that you don't provide `-mmcu=dev` option to GCC when linking. It is therefore unable to find proper `crt*.o` file (C RunTime) and tell the linker to link it in; your application ends up without any initialization code.

So please note that you must include `-mmcu=dev` in LDFLAGS or pass it to GCC regardless of what it is meant to do (preprocessing/compilation/assemblation/linking). I've already seen a couple of makefiles without this option in LDFLAGS on the Internet, so beware.

---

Now it's time for some practice -- assuming that your source is in `test.c` file, issue the following commands (on linux):

```
avr-gcc -mmcu=attiny13a -DF_CPU=1200000 -Wall -O1 -c -o testO1.o test.c
avr-gcc -mmcu=attiny13a -DF_CPU=1200000 -Wall -Os -c -o testOs.o test.c
avr-gcc -o testO1_nodev.elf testO1.o
avr-gcc -v -o testOs_nodev.elf testOs.o > testOs_nodev.log 2>&1
avr-gcc -v -mmcu=attiny13a -o testOs_correct.elf testOs.o > testOs_correct.log 2>&1
```

I left only necessary options + `-Wall`, for ATtiny13a you need `-mmcu=attiny13a` instead of `-mmcu=attiny13`.

Let's take a look at `testOs_nodev.log` and `testOs_correct.log`. Issue the following command:

```
diff testOs_nodev.log testOs_correct.log
```

and you will see something like:

```
2c2
< Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/device-specs/specs-avr2
---
> Reading specs from /usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/device-specs/specs-attiny13a
10,12c10,12
< LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/../../../../avr/lib/
< COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-o' 'testOs_nodev.elf' '-specs=device-specs/specs-avr2'
<  /usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/liblto_plugin.so \
-plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccqBjM6T.res \
-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lm -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc \ 
-o testOs_nodev.elf -L/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/../../../../avr/lib \
testOs.o --start-group -lgcc -lm -lc --end-group
---
> LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/avr25/tiny-stack/:\
/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/../../../../avr/lib/avr25/tiny-stack/:\
/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/../../../../avr/lib/
> COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v'  '-o' 'testOs_correct.elf' '-specs=device-specs/specs-attiny13a' \
'-mmcu=avr25' '-msp8'
>  /usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/collect2 -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/liblto_plugin.so \
-plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/lto-wrapper -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccV919rY.res \
-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lm -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lc \
-plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lattiny13a -mavr25 -o testOs_correct.elf \
/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/../../../../avr/lib/avr25/tiny-stack/crtattiny13a.o \
-L/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/avr25/tiny-stack -L/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/../../../../avr/lib/avr25/tiny-stack \
-L/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/avr/5.2.0/../../../../avr/lib testOs.o \
--start-group -lgcc -lm -lc -lattiny13a --end-group
```

(I broke a few lines to make it readable)

The difference is that without `-mmcu=dev` option GCC defaults to use avr2 specs file and doesn't link any CRT file.

Examine object files (`*.o`) and output files (`*.elf`) using avr-objdump:

```
avr-objdump -xd testOs_nodev.elf
```

You will notice that `*_nodev.elf` files don't contain correct information about architecture (avr instead of avr:25) nor any startup code (compare `testOs_correct.elf` with `testOs_nodev.elf`). The code section seems to a verbatim copy of what was supplied in object file.

---

If any part of my elaboration seems unclear or needs extra explanation, feel free to ask (comment).